# BlackBerry Android Runtime ADB failed

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I try to Packaging project with **Android Runtime For BlackBerry** I done every thing
-Simulator, ADT- for eclipse .. **when i test the app i got this error :**

```
[2013-04-13 13:16:04 - BlackBerryTest] Packaging project BlackBerryTest
[2013-04-13 13:16:11 - BlackBerryTest] Launching BlackBerry Android Runtime...
[2013-04-13 13:16:20 - BlackBerryTest] Connecting to ADB...
[2013-04-13 13:17:23 - BlackBerryTest] Status ERROR: net.rim.ajde code=4 Connecting 192.168.72.128 to ADB failed!   null children=[Status ERROR: net.rim.ajde code=0 Please check if the Android player was fully started when you got this error. If not, you can either increase the Android player launch timeout on the BlackBerry->BlackBerry Android Development Tools preference page or wait until the Android player is fully started and try again. null]
```

in the Simulator there is splash screen contain **blackberry 10 logo** start about 2 sec and then close and eclipse still **Connecting to ADB...** about a minute then I got error to connect.

**

**UPDATE :**

**

Now I  got this message

```
04-25 12:01:15.539: I/navigatorshell(17789061): no app URI, just launch AP and exit
```

**Any Idea ?**

Answer (score 2):

This is usually caused by the Android Runtime taking a very long time to load, and in some cases, never actually loading.

The root cause is that the simulator is running very slowly. If you haven't already, **enable virtualisation in your BIOS**, this makes a massive difference to simulator performance and solved this issue for me.

There's a video about this here: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/08/performance-increase-blackberry-10-simulator/

Comment: thanks, really now its very fast , but i got this message 
04-25 12:01:15.539: I/navigatorshell(17789061): no app URI, just launch AP and exit

Comment: Try performing a hard reset on the phone, then try again